# PlayerPref issue, Cant find .plist files on windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using playerPref on my character creation and I need to find the plist files. I already read the API doc on playerPref. I went on unity, changed the company and game name, then I went to regedit > HKCU/software/CompanyName/GameName. The file is there but there aren't any .plist files. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be beneficial to save your data into a savegame instead. Any human readable format like `Json` or `XML` will help you greate deal.

Answer (score 3):

plist can be only found in Mac OSX, as is documented [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

> On Mac OS X PlayerPrefs are stored in ~/Library/Preferences folder, in a file named unity.[company name].[product name].plist, where company and product names are the names set up in Project Settings. The same .plist file is used for both Projects run in the Editor and standalone players.
>
> On Windows, PlayerPrefs are stored in the registry under **HKCU\Software[company name][product name] key**, where company and product names are the names set up in Project Settings.
>
> On Linux, PlayerPrefs can be found in ~/.config/unity3d/[CompanyName]/[ProductName] again using the company and product names specified in the Project Settings.
>
> On Windows Store Apps, Player Prefs can be found in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages[ProductPackageId]>\LocalState\playerprefs.dat
>
> On Windows Phone 8, Player Prefs can be found in application's local folder, See Also: Windows.Directory.localFolder

So you should find registry key values, instead of plist.

"the file is there but there isnt .plist files", there is no file in registry, so it is impossible to be "there", what you see is registry key, but not files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Unity 5.6.1 Windows Editor I found at **HKCU\Software\Unity\UnityEditor[company name][product name] key**.